# Read data from JSON file using class library project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a file called 'MyConfig.json' in my Class Library Dotnet core project. Now I need to read the content of this `json` file. The content should be able to access from a Model class.

So, when I say `User.FirstName` I should be able to retrieve the `UserName` part of the JSON or else by giving the `key`. How can i do this ?

Below is what I tried, but I am not able to retrieve its content.

```
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        
        builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../MyConfig.json"));
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?  it might be helpful if you post the relevant portion of your json file

```
 IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("MyConfig.json");

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            User.FisrtName = configuration["userName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set properties of your config file so it always gets copied into output folder
[image]

**.\MyConfig.json**

```
{
  "User": {
    "FirstName": "test"
  }
}
```

Code

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddJsonFile("MyConfig.json");

            var config = builder.Build();

            var section = config.GetSection("User");
            var user = section.Get<User>();
        }
    }
}
```